# How can I make my React Component mount, when the right url is accessed and the user is not logged in?

Tags: reactjs, url, react-redux, react-router

My App.js:

```
        <Nav info={this.props}/>
        {this.props.loading === true
          ? null
          : <div>
            {this.props.authedUser
              ? <Switch>
                  <Route path='/' exact component={Dashboard}/>
                  <Route path='/question/:id' exact component={QPage}/>
                  <Route path='/new' exact component={CreateQ}/>
                  <Route path='/leaderboard' exact component={Leaderboard}/>
                  <Route path='/sign-in' exact component={SignIn}/>
                  <Route component={Error}/> 
                </Switch>
              : <Route path='/sign-in' component={SignIn}/>
            }                  
            </div>
        }
```

My app shows a Nav bar at the top. It has a button that says **Logout**. When the button is clicked, I am clearing the *authedUser* behind the scenes in my Redux store and navigate to the '/sign-in' url. All of this works, but when the '/sign-in' url is accessed, my **SignIn** component doesn't get rendered. But when I reload, the **SignIn** component does get rendered.

After the user is being logged out, App.js get re-rendered. Then the ternary operator should actually be false (because this.props.authedUser is null) and it should render the route and its component **SignIn**. But this doesn't seem to happen.
How can I make sure, that the **SignIn** component does get rendered, when the ternary operator returns false?

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the `props.loading` flag? I mean if it becomes `true` everything disappears and after reloading, when this flag gets initial value, the `SignIn` component shows up at `sign-in ` path

Comment: @RamilGaripov Thank you so much man. You were so right. The loading had an effect on the rest of the rendering. Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

When `authedUser` is false app.js is re-render with out

```
<Switch>
  <Route path='/' exact component={Dashboard}/>
  <Route path='/question/:id' exact component={QPage}/>
  <Route path='/new' exact component={CreateQ}/>
  <Route path='/leaderboard' exact component={Leaderboard}/>
  <Route path='/sign-in' exact component={SignIn}/>
  <Route component={Error}/> 
</Switch>
```

so... when you navigate the user to `/sign-in` the route those not exists

In order to achive your goal, you can do this:

```
App.js

<Switch>
  <Route path='/' exact component={Dashboard}/>
  <Route path='/main' exact component={Main}/>
  <Route path='/sign-in' exact component={SignIn}/>
  <Route component={Error}/> 
</Switch>
```

After a succesfull login, you will do history.push('/main'),
and in Main.js all the authenticated routes will be managed

```
Main.js
... your code...
if (!this.props.authedUser) {
  return <Redirect to='/sign-in' />
};

return (
  <Switch>
    <Route path='/question/:id' exact component={QPage}/>
    <Route path='/new' exact component={CreateQ}/>
    <Route path='/leaderboard' exact component={Leaderboard}/>
  </Switch>
)
```

and when you will want to navigate a user to some route:

```
history.push('/main/leaderboard')
```

Comment: FYI, switch is deprecated by react router and removed in version 7.